# JQL to retrieve results when summary or description has alphanumeric text

Tags: jira, jql

I currently require a JQL query that will pull all the issues when the
summary field contains "ABC1234567"
or description contains "ABC1234567"
or links to "ABC"

I'm able to retrieve results from the below JQL when they have an ABC external link to the issue. I'm not able to retrieve issues that has ABC1234567 in summary or description.

**MY JQL:**
summary ~ "ABC.right(7)" OR description ~ "ABC.right(7)" OR issueFunction in linkedIssuesOfRemote("ABC*")) AND status not in (closed, de-scoped, released)

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.